# asynch methods with web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

I want to call a method from a web service.

I think what happen in sync mode is

`var obj = new SalesOrder.CustServicesSoapClient();
obj.AddProduct(txtName.Text, txtColor.Text)`

wait for response and then

`ResSpan.innerHTML="foo";`

but in async mode:

`var obj = new SalesOrder.CustServicesSoapClient();`

`obj.AddProductAsync(txtName.Text, txtColor.Text)`

next line run independent of previous line

`ResSpan.innerHTML="foo";`

the code implemented in a void method, so the method will wait until `AddProductAsync' is being finished.

I wonder if let me know is it correct understanding of `async methods'?

Comment: what is the question? this is how async works.... it is a NON BLOCKING call.

Comment: Please, read [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45 "Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5 ").

Answer (score 1):

Async methods are asynchronous - this means that they do not block the main execution thread and will occur in parallel at some point. If you need to wait for an `async` call to finish you need to either await the response (if using async/await), call `Wait()` (if using a `Task<T>`) to wait for it to finish or access the `Result` property (which also implicitly calls `Wait`).

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has a fantastic [EduAsync](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx) series that will take you through async from nuts to bolts.

Comment: I'm sure Jon Skeet isn't telling anyone to use `Wait` and `Result` like that, but Steve [explains why](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html "Don't Block on Async Code ").